# Install printer in openSUSE 12.1?

Tags: opensuse, printing

My laptop was reformatted, from Windows to openSUSE 12.1.

How to install the printer?

Comment: the answer to this may depend on your printer. please edit your question to include the make and model. also, if you are new to Linux i would suggest Ubuntu, which is in part specifically aimed at people who are new to Linux and generally has more programs available as packages.

Comment: Which is the model of the printer?

Answer (score 2):

There is a configuration tool in openSUSE called [YaST](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal%3aYaST), which can be used to configure various aspects of the system, including printers (amongst many other things).

There is a [wikipage](http://en.opensuse.org/YaST_Printer) which should help you with configuring the printer using YaST printer module. If it does not, please let us know what exactly does not work so that will be hopefully able to help you.